# changing a global variable in a class function

Tags: c++, function, variables, global

I am trying to get a global variable called aliensKilled to increase whenever my collision function between a PlayerMissile and Alien is called.

// main

```
   // Global Variables:
   HINSTANCE hInst;                             // current instance
   TCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                   // The title bar text
   TCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];         // the main window class name
   int aliensKilled = 0;
```

//PlayerBullet class

```
   void
```

PlayerBullet::Update(float dt_)
{

```
float Speed=2.0f;
int rNum = rand()%75;
m_fY+=Speed*dt_;

if (m_fY > 2.5) TagForDeletion();

//check for collision with an alien
CSprite * collidingObject =g_pGame->CheckForCollision(
                                    this, eSpriteTypeAlien);
if (collidingObject)
{
    //delete colliding object
    collidingObject->TagForDeletion();
    //delete self
    this->TagForDeletion();
    //collidingObject->GetAliensKilled();
    aliensKilled++; 


    if (rNum < 5)
    {
        g_pGame->AddSprite(new Powerup(m_fX, m_fY+0.5*m_fH, 0.9, 0.9, 0));
        //delete colliding object
        collidingObject->TagForDeletion();
        //delete self
        this->TagForDeletion();

    }
}

CSprite * collidingObjectbar =g_pGame-`enter code here`
```

I know this is an incredibly simple and minimalist way of doing this but I have       tried more complex methods such as using a GetAliensKilled() method, or using a static function and nothing seems to compile. I just wanted to show what I was trying to do in its most basic form. My deadline is tomorrow and any help would be brilliant. 
Thanks for reading.

Comment: What's the problem? What errors do you get? Just so you know, pasting random lines from a big program is not helpful; all of those functions and variables mean absolutely nothing to us. Typically when debugging you produce a [_testcase_](http://sscce.org) for yourself and work on that.

Comment: OK hang on, ill read through this and repost the question, thanks.

Comment: Did you declare `extern int aliensKilled;` in your PlayerBullet source?

Comment: Wow, that actually fixed it, I feel like I should research why it worked but for now I will just accept that it does, thanks a lot mate, you have saved my life.

Comment: I wish I knew what the actual problem was here.